# TransformException duplicate entry for GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android

After a re-install of Android Studio following a disk failure, I have updated the dependencies for my project to reflect API 21.  This introduced the use of multiDex, so my build.gradle now contains:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.+'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
}
```

Please note I don't want to update to API 23 at this stage for consistency with a sister application.

I keep getting the following error when I try to build:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging$1.class

I added the 'exclude group' lines to the dependencies only when trying to resolve the duplication.

Cleaning the project makes no difference (I've tried from both the terminal and the Studio menu).

The output from `./gradlew app:dependencies` is as follows:

```
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 22.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 22.2.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.+ -> 7.8.0
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
```

Apologies if this is a duplication of another SO question, but I've looked at other questions and they haven't helped, as I can't see where the duplication is introduced.  Can anyone tell me the source of the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, and just to try to help if anyone else sees something similar...
This was a project which had been imported into Studio from Eclipse and there was still a Google Play Services jar in the libs folder, hence the clash with the gradle dependency.
I couldn't tell the jar was there from the Studio interface though, I had to look directly in the folder, and it was only the introduction of multiDex which produced an error.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue,,Please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874487/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entrycom-google-android-gms-auth-userreco