# I am having this error when I try to run my android project:

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback$1.class

Here is my build(Module:app).gradle & build.gradle(Project:AppName) files
  [In this image i don't understand where changes are need to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u90CN.png)[build.gradle file having multiple dependencies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEz2h.png)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35082883/6248491

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/3). firebase-jobdispatcher-android comes bundled with gcm and since you have already have it in your dependencies, you get the duplicate entry error.

Sampyng suggests you do the following:

```
compile ("com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0") {
    exclude module: "play-services-gcm"
```

}